# Cannot see my Data in Tables

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

I am creating a simple WPF Application with a Sql Connection. The problem is that when i debug 
the program it seems to be OK ( no errors ), but i cannot see my Data in the database.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

        conn.ConnectionString = @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MIKE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Customer](FirstName,LastName) VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName)", conn);

            conn.Open();

            // Insert code to process data.
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", CUCFirstName.Text);
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", CUClastName.Text);

            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Number.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

and my xaml code

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Content="Add" Height="66" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,233,0,0" 
            Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="135" Click="button1_Click" />

    <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,32,0,0" Name="CUCFirstName" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,74,0,0" Name="CUClastName" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242">
    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="First Name" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,32,0,0" 
           Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" />

    <Label Content="Last Name" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,72,0,0" 
           Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The database is being copied in the Debug\Bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run the application a new instance of your database is copied to your debug folder (Because it is considered as resource).Put your database some where in local hard-drive like "C:\Test" and specify the same path in connection string.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I searched it and i forgot to put the Database Name in the 
ConnectionString and in the app.config

    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MIKE.mdf;**Database=MIKE**;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Its working now